# ClassCastException using OrientDb

Tags: java, nosql, classcastexception, orientdb

I am a newbie in orientdb and I am trying to save some entities in the database but I keep having this exception :

```
    GRAVE: Error on creating object of class SessionStats
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.heavenize.embedder.statsengine.model.SessionStats_$$_javassist_0 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.enhancement.OObjectEntityEnhancer.getProxiedInstance(OObjectEntityEnhancer.java:155)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.newInstance(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:132)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.newInstance(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:92)
 ....
```

I have using  Object Database to persist some objects and I have created a class to wrap the `OObjectDatabaseTx` class.

The exception happends when I am trying to create a new instance.

```
 public class DbOrientService
{

  public <T> T newIntance(Class<T> instance)
  {
    OObjectDatabaseTx currentDbInstance = getCurrentDbInstance();
    T newInstance = currentDbInstance.newInstance(instance); //Happens in this line
    return newInstance;
  }

   public OObjectDatabaseTx getCurrentDbInstance()
  {
    this.db = new OObjectDatabaseTx(url);
    if (!this.db.exist())
    {          
      this.db = db.create();
    }
    else
    {
      this.db = OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire(url, "admin", "admin");
    }
    return db;
  }
```

I also registered the package where the entities are stored. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.heavenize.embedder.statsengine.model.SessionStats_$$_javassist_0
cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
```

Since the object obviously *is* a javassist proxy and can't be casted to javassist proxy, I'd assume that you have two different versions of javassist on the classpath

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Classpath confusion between Eclipse and maven.